# Switch back to default font on widening

Tags: fonts, narrowing, default, indirect-buffers

Running emacs 25.2.2 on Kubuntu 17.10.

I have an Org mode file that is mostly in English but certain headlines contain text in Devanagari.

From Options -> Set Default Font, I have chosen Hack 13 size as my default font.

But Hack is not a good font to display Devanagari characters.

So, when I want to edit contents of those headlines, I narrow the buffer to that region using `C-x n s` and using `C-x C-e`, evaluate the following command which is part of the headline:

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Lohit Devanagari")
```

But that still changes the font for the entire buffer when I widen using `C-x n w`.

How do I achieve the behavior that I intend? Change the font back to the default when I widen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use library [`narrow-indirect.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el) to help here.

Use command `ni-narrow-to-region-indirect-other-window` (I bind it to **`C-x 4 n n`**) to open an *indirect buffer* that shows just the current region (e.g. of Devanagari text).

There, you can use your `(face-remap-add-relative 'default :family "Lohit Devanagari")` to change that buffer's font, for Devanagari. The base buffer (and other indirect narrowing buffers) retains the font it had.

See [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect) for more information.

---

Update to answer your comment question:

Library `narrow-indirect.el` is not distributed with Emacs.  It is available on the Emacs Wiki.  You download it, put it in your `load-path`, and then `require` it, as follows:

1. Right-click the [`narrow-indirect.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/narrow-indirect.el) link, and choose *Save Link As* (or whatever your browser uses for this), to save the file.
2. Save the file in a directory that is in your `load-path`: Put this in your init file:

   ```
    (add-to-list 'load-path "/YOUR/LISP/DIRECTORY/")
    (require 'narrow-indirect)
   ```

The first expression tells Emacs where to find the library.  The second expression tells Emacs to load the library.

See the Emacs manual, node [Lisp Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html) and the Elisp library, node [How Programs Do Loading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html), for more info about this.

Comment: Thanks. This solution would have been perfect except that I am not able to locate narrow-indirect.el. So, when I try `M-x ni-narrow-to-region-indirect-other-window`, it shows no matches. When I tried looking for narrow-indirect using `M-x list-packages` or `M-x load-library`, there is no narrow-indirect. Am I missing something here?